# Process every timestep of a Keras Input before insterting into a LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm

**Introduction:**

I want rebuild a neural network I found in a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02096.pdf). The network, containing an biLSTM, takes a series of characters and turns them into a series of integers which is padded by zeros and calculates a vector representation of this series of characters, which is therefore the representation of the word*. The network providing these embeddings is called a char2vector-, C2W-network, which will help later undestanding. These word embeddings, calculated from the charater sequences, are then feeded into an LSTM for language modeling. The language modeling takes the vector representation and tries to predict the next word from it.

*For example the word 'hello' is transforemd into the sequnce of chars ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] which is further transformed into a sequnce of integers representing the characters [5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, ...] and the nework calculates a vector from that sequence with an biLSTM.

So a sentence is represented in the frist place by a sequnce of words, which themselves are represented by a sequence of chars. Char sequnces are padded by zeros to the maximum possible number of chars, and sentences are padded by words, which are only a sequnce of zeros ([0, 0, 0, 0, ...]). So my input shape is (batch_size, max_num_words, max_num_chars) and therefore I can use a lot of masking, in order to reduce computation time

**My problem:**

I need to process every timestep (which equals a word) by the C2W-network and the outcome of that first layer is then inserted into the LSTM. So I want to transform an Input with the shape (bath_size, max_num_words, max_num_chars) into a tensor with the shape (batch_size, max_num_words, embedding_dimension). But I do not know how to handle that. How do I construct a layer, which takes every timestep of the input and transforms it. Can I construct a layer, which puts every timestep of the Input into a function and combines all the outcomes to a new tensor? I tried around a lot and tried to find examples, but I have not been successful yet. I hope someone here can help.

**The code I used so far:**

sent_max_len = maximum length of a sentence, the +1 is used for the start-of-sentence- and end-of-sentence-token for Input and Output respectively

char_max_len = maximum length of a word

char2idx = dictionary that transforms a char into an integer, e.g. 'a': 2, 'b': 3, etc.

word2idx = dictionary that transforms a word into an integer, e.g. 'hello': 2, 'my': 3, 'friend': 4, etc.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Masking
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras import backend as K

sent_input = Input((sent_max_len+1, word_max_len), dtype = 'int32')

c2w_model = Sequential()
c2w_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = len(char2idx), output_dim = 32, input_length = word_max_len, mask_zero = True))
c2w_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(cw_dim, 
                             return_sequences=False, 
                             use_bias=True, 
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                             return_state = False
                            ), merge_mode='concat'))
c2w_model.add(Dense(50, use_bias=True))

# C2W_Layer calculates the the word representation of every word 
# and combines the outcoming tensors to the final input 
C2W_Layer = Lambda(lambda tensor: K.concatenate([c2w_model(tensor[i]) for i in range(K.eval(tensor.shape[0]))], 
                                                axis = 0), mask = True)

l1_masking = Masking(mask_value = 0.0)(sent_input)
l2_encoding = C2W_Layer(l1_masking)
l3_lstm = LSTM(st_dim, return_sequences = True)(l2_encoding)
l4_prediction = Dense(len(word2idx), activation = 'softmax')(l3_lstm)
seq_model = Model(inputs = sent_input, outputs = l4_prediction)

opt = SGD(learning_rate = lr, momentum = 0.95)

seq_model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt)
```

This setup returns the following error:

```
MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start from 0), used to compute Elemwise{neq,no_inplace}(lambda_3/lambda_4/lambda_5/input_6, InplaceDimShuffle{x,x,x}.0), was not provided and not given a value.
```

Therefore I played around, trying other possibilites to take every time step and calculates its vector representation. The farthest I came with the following setup, which seems to my quite squishy, as every word has its own input layer:

```
sent_inputs = []
for _ in range(sent_max_len+1):
    sent_inputs.append(Input((word_max_len, ), dtype = 'int32'))

c2w_model = Sequential()
c2w_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = len(char2idx), output_dim = 32, input_length = word_max_len, mask_zero = True))
c2w_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(cw_dim, 
                             return_sequences=False, 
                             use_bias=True, 
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                             return_state = False
                            ), merge_mode='concat'))
c2w_model.add(Dense(50, use_bias=True))
c2w_model.add(Reshape((1, 50)))

embedded_inputs = [c2w_model(imp) for imp in sent_inputs]
l1_encoding = Concatenate(axis = 0)(embedded_inputs)
l3_lstm = LSTM(st_dim, return_sequences = True)(l1_encoding)
l4_prediction = Dense(len(self.word2idx), activation = 'softmax')(l3_lstm)
seq_model = Model(inputs = sent_inputs, outputs = l4_prediction)

opt = SGD(learning_rate = lr, momentum = 0.95)

seq_model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt)
```

In this case, I can at least compile the model, although I am not able to use masking anymore, but I wanted it at least to run once. But again I get an error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (96114, 31)

dense_24 is the very last layer within the model.

I hope someone has an idea how to solve that!

Comment: set return_sequences = False in your last LSTM layer

Comment: Can you elaborate this setting? Every input word should be used to predict the following word in the sentence, so for the language modelling return_sequences = True seems to be a necessity.